# File include works but Virtual include doesn't

Tags: apache, iis, ssi, server-side-includes

I'm working on a website and am using MAMP built in server for local development. In my site I want to use SSI and am .shtml to do so. I have a testing server which is Apache and the files are going to eventually end up on an IIS server, and I was told doing this type of include will work in both environments. I got   to work on the local environment but when I tried to put it on the testing Apache server I get an "SSI error". And the weird thing is if I change it to  , it works fine on the testing Apache server but doesn't work on the local environment. I have a very basic understanding of this but am wondering if there is a reason "virtual" works locally but not on testing and "file" works on testing but not local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an example of the includes, it's difficult to offer suggestions. I'll take a stab in the dark though.

Both the `file` and `virtual` attributes depend completely on how the web server in question is configured.

The `file` path depends on how the filesystem is made available to the relevant web server - try traversing to the `file` path from the point where it's called on both your 'local' and 'test' web servers.

The `virtual` path depends on how the document root is mapped to URIs being called against the relevant web server - try requesting the `virtual` URI path against both your 'local' and 'test' web servers.

These debugging steps should indicate where the configuration differs between the two environments.